# Solution of Certain Number Theoretic Problems.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image]

I was going through the text "Elementary Number Theory - David M. Burton." There I found some problems posed by Paul Erdos. I want to know how many of these problems has been solved till date. It will be highly appreciated if you also give me the respective references.

**P.S.** I think I have some idea to solve the $3$rd problem that is the reason why I want to know whether these have been solved already or not.

Comment: For problem 5 see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions Also this might be of help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_conjectures_by_Paul_Erd%C5%91s

Comment: Did you try to use CRT to solve P4?

Comment: For problem 1, $1$ is not of the form $2^k+n$ with $n$ square-free.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattachrya I don't have any idea how can we use CRT for this problem.

Comment: @mathlove If you write $1 = 2^{k}+n$ you will get the value of $n = 0$.Since Square free numbers are defined only for natural numbers therefore we should not consider this case.

Comment: @SARTHAKGUPTA: "If you write $1=2^k +n$ you will get the value of $n=0$. Since Square free numbers are defined only for natural numbers" I agree, and you *unintentionally* showed that $1$ is not of that form. So, you *unintentionally* showed that the answer to problem 1 is yes. The problem 1 is such a easy question. If we have another problem saying "Does there exist an odd integer **larger than $1$** that is not of the form $2^k+n$ with $n$ square-free?", then it seems difficult. "therefore we should not consider this case" No, we **should** consider the case since $1$ is an odd integer.